# jquery fixed header after 200 scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I had a code here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/udeeH/2/). I can't make it scroll fixed after 200 scroll.

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
            $('navbar').css('position', 'fixed');
            $('navbar').slideDown();
        } else if ($(this).scrollTop() <= 200) {
            $('navbar').removeClass('position', 'relative');
            $('navbar').slideUp();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `$('.navbar')` you need for one

Comment: Your fiddle is set up wrong. Code is executing onload and you are attaching an onload event in there. Not going to fire.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/udeeH/8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `.` in `navbar` since it is a `class` and change the first line to `$(function () {`

No need to execute a `load` function in your code when you are using `onload` event already.

Also, as mentioned in the comments:

Change:

```
$('.navbar').removeClass('position', 'relative');
```

To:

```
$('.navbar').css('position', 'relative');
```

Try this:

```
$(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
            $('.navbar').css('position', 'fixed');
            $('.navbar').slideDown();
        } else if ($(this).scrollTop() <= 200) {
            $('.navbar').css('position', 'relative');
            $('.navbar').slideUp();
        }
    });
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/udeeH/10/)**

Comment: Need to fix `$('.navbar').removeClass('position', 'relative');`

Comment: @Huangism thank you for that! Didn't realize... Updated!

Answer (score 0):

Not `.removeClass` this one is `.css`

Try

```
$('.navbar').css('position', 'relative');
```

instead of

```
$('.navbar').removeClass('position', 'relative');
```